# Parse HTACCESS directive arguments

Tags: delphi, parsing, .htaccess, arguments, quotes

Following my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112069/tokenize-htaccess-files), I need to parse directive arguments, like these:

```
Listen 80
```

The parameters can get a bit complicated, with any kind of whitespace between arguments as well as escaped arguments.

My objective is to get a "complex" argument list like this:

```
cmd "C:\Documents and Settings\..." "msg=\"hello\"" msg="hello" "msg=""hello"""
```

into a TStringList of:

```
N | Text
--+-------------------------------
0 | cmd
1 | C:\Documents and Settings\...
2 | msg="hello"
3 | msg="hello"
4 | msg="hello"
```

One of my questions concern how quotes are escaped. I have two examples above, argument 2 and argument 4. In the first one, escaping is done by having a slash before the quote, while the second one is done by converting double (double)quotes into a single quote, a syntax associated with pascal (I think?)

How would I go about parsing the arguments efficiently in objective pascal (Delphi)?

Comment: I think I'd get the Apache source code and use that.

Comment: I will when hell freezes over...

Comment: Have you considered using [Gold Parser](http://goldparser.org/)?

Comment: @menjaraz - A parser parser? Nah, the syntax is easy enough to write my own. In fact, that's what I did...